# Not able to access website with IP adress outside VPS

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8

I am facing problem in accessing my website from IP address with a port rather than port 80. I have a VPS and hosted a website in IIS. I created a new website and assigned port as 8080. I am able to access my website as localhost:8080/ but not able to access it through IP-Address:8080/ inside or outside VPS.

But if I host my website in default website as an application then I can access it inside or outside VPS. I am able to access it as localhost/mysitename/ and as IP-Address/mysitename/.

Comment: If its very urgent, then contact your VPS support. StackOverflow is not for technical support emergencies. Have you checked your firewall? Do you have any port restrictions that are preventing the other port 8080 from reaching IIS?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Please read your words before commenting.

Comment: This old question was not resolved here, I'm voting to put on hold. OP, would you consider deleting it?

Answer (score 0):

You must go and check your VPS firewall. You must define a rule to open  tcp 8080 port on it.

Comment: I tried on/off VPS firewall but no success. I also tried creating inbound and outbound rule to open TCP port. Inside VPS it was working but publicly there was no effect on it.